# How do I show more tabs when Ctrl Tabbing on Firefox?

Tags: firefox

Using Ctrl + Tab to quickly change to another tab in Firefox only shows 7 tabs.

Is it possible to change some config or preference so that there is a bigger number of tabs shown? Perhaps instead of one row of tabs, there becomes several?

Thanks

Comment: Hi @stapmoshun,
It seems that it is the current limit of MRU Switcher.
There is a request at **Mozilla Connect** to increase that limit: [Increase Number of tabs in ctrl+tab tab mru switcher](https://connect.mozilla.org/t5/ideas/increase-number-of-tabs-in-ctrl-tab-tab-mru-switcher/idi-p/747)
Maybe you could vote it to increase the probability that the application will be attended.
Beyond this, it is highly likely that there is an extension that provides something like the functionality you are looking for.